Jest mock db constant
I want to test an Express API with Jest.
In a test suite I want to test routes which modify the database so I have a testdb file (SQLite) which I copy and paste in a temporary directory and tests should work on the copy.
Now my app works like this: I have a database.mjs wrapper module
import sqlite3 from 'sqlite3'
import { open } from 'sqlite'

export const database = await open({
    filename: 'database.sqlite3',
    driver: sqlite3.Database
})

which is used by index.mjs which is my express app.
Now In my test file I cannot figure out jest.mock, jest.spyOn, jest.fn to mock my database with another one. I have followed this related question to no avail.
import * as fs from 'node:fs/promises';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';
import { database } from '../modules/database.mjs';
import * as dbmodule from '../modules/database.mjs';
import sqlite3 from 'sqlite3'
import { open } from 'sqlite'
import { server } from "../index.mjs";
import { jest } from '@jest/globals'

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
const dirnameDBState = __dirname + "/db_state"
const dirnameTmp = __dirname + "/.tmp"
const filenameDBState1 = "testdb1.sqlite3"
const filenameTmpDBState1 = `${dirnameTmp}/${filenameDBState1}`


beforeAll(async () => {
    await fs.mkdir(dirnameTmp)
    await fs.copyFile(`${dirnameDBState}/${filenameDBState1}`, filenameTmpDBState1)
    const mockDatabase = await open({
        filename: filenameTmpDBState1,
        driver: sqlite3.Database
    })
    jest.mock('../modules/database.mjs', () => ({ database: mockDatabase }))
    jest.resetModules()
    console.log(filenameTmpDBState1, database)
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10_000));
})

afterAll(async () => {
    try { server.close() }
    finally { await fs.rm(dirnameTmp, { recursive: true, force: true }) }
})

test('Simple test', async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/user/register', {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email: 'test.user@gmail.com', password: 'testPassword', role: 'ADMIN' })
    })
})

What I have tried or though of:

Using jest.fn doesn't work for me because I don't want to mock a function but an exported constant
Since I have declared database as const I should not be able to simply assign to dbmodule a new value with dbmodule.database = mockDatabase

The problem I am having is that the test doesn't use the mock
